# Build custom Master Page for Office 365 site

Tags: office-365, custom-masterpage

Does anyone have any idea of how to get a free template or working example to edit Office 365 master page?

I have a requirement where I need to change the complete default layout of Office 365 to my custom style.

It is not for the public facing site, this is for internal portal which uses Office 365 (SharePoint 2013 version)

Comment: It works the same as the on premise version. Copy the Oslo.master html file and start customizing.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a HTML document which will later work as your masterpage on SharePoint. Follow this guide and it should help you achieve your goal:

[How to: Convert an HTML file into a master page in SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj822370.aspx)

Comment: this is not applicable or possible for intranet site.

Answer (score 0):

This article on SharePoint Custom Master Page. Helped me in getting the Old SharePoint features back.

http://sharepointsolutions-sudheer.blogspot.com/2020/04/custom-master-page-modern-site-sharepoint-online.html

Answer (score -3):

I don't know yet any free template for the 2013 version of the Office 365, however on this site http://www.bindtuning.com/cms/sharepoint/office-365-v2013/themes you can find some cheap themes that work for the public facing sites and the SharePoint sites they are fully customizable and also include a lot of features that are not included by default in the Office 365

Comment: Please note that, [per the FAQ](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) you must disclose your affiliation in your answers. If your objective is to quietly drum up a bit of traffic for your site, this is probably the wrong place for you. [mod]